# How to include libsigar in an sbt-native-packager rpm build?

Tags: rpm, sbt-native-packager

I'm trying to build an rpm package with sbt-native-packager and I'd like to include the sigar binaries. I'm getting an error " error: Arch dependent binaries in noarch package" and setting packageArchitecture doesn't seem to help. Any suggestions on how to configure this appropriately?

I'm currently adding the sigar dependencies via unmanagedDependencies.

Comment: This is a very interesting question. Can you open a bug for this: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/new

Comment: Done. https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/375

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick-and-dirty solution was posted here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/375 which simply disables the rpm check for architecture dependent dependencies.

```
rpmPre := Some("%global _binaries_in_noarch_packages_terminate_build 0")
```

or

rpmPre := Some("#%define _binaries_in_noarch_packages_terminate_build 0")

Currently sbt-native-packager only supports inclusion of one specific architecture, and support for multiple is listed as a feature request.